# ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Why do I get this error?

> ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype

The code:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = np.array (cols)
cols2 = cols[:17] + cols[19:22] + cols [18]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues

- operator `+`, when used on `numpy` array, is interpreted as numerical addition, not list concatenation, thus the error about the matching dtype. Instead of addition, you should use `np.concatenate`
- `cols[18]` is not an array -- it is an element of the array. You cannot add a number and a array (if what you want to do is to append the element to the array)

```
cols2 = np.concatenate([cols[:17], cols[19:22], [cols[18]]])
```

or you can keep cols as a list (not converting it to `numpy` array and use list addition):

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols2 = cols[:17] + cols[19:22] + [cols[18]]
```

Comment: The  error is becuse cols is one column with 23 rows. So how can i crate a new vector with columns - 0-10 + 15-20 + 20-21 ? TY

Comment: As I said, you can either use list addition, or numpy concatenate. I think list addition is better `cols = df.columns.tolist(); cols2 = cols[:11] + cols[15:21] + cols[21:22]` (but don't convert `cols` to `np.array`)